# lambda sequence in glmnet in ridge vs lasso

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm having a problem with ridge cv in `glmnet` calculating an unreasonable lambda sequence.
I"m running both ridge and lasso regression with `glmnet` using the exact same data. Lasso is fine, but ridge isn't.

```
ridge.cv <- cv.glmnet(preds[train.i,], resp[train.i], alpha=0, family="binomial", type.measure="class")
lasso.cv <- cv.glmnet(preds[train.i,], resp[train.i], alpha=1, family="binomial", type.measure="class")

range(lasso.cv$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio)
[1] 1.117039e-14 9.334558e-01

range(ridge.cv$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio)
[1] 1.117039e-14 1.852909e-01

> range( lasso.cv$lambda)
[1]   0.002812585 0.268474838

> range(ridge.cv$lambda)
[1]   2.812585 268.474838
```

So, Lasso calculates a reasonable lambda sequence, yielding a reasonable range of deviance explained. However, Ridge calculates a lambda sequence exactly 1000 times higher than that of lasso, yielding a ridiculous range of deviance explained. Dimensions of predictor matrix is 891 x 1028

Any idea why might that happen and how to fix it? I can of course input my own sequence, but I'd like to know why it happens in case it is just a symptom of a bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the `glmnet` help file:

> lambda: The actual sequence of ‘lambda’ values used. When ‘alpha=0’,          the largest lambda reported does not quite give the zero coefficients reported (‘lambda=inf’ would in principle). Instead, the largest ‘lambda’ for ‘alpha=0.001’ is used, and the sequence of ‘lambda’ values is derived from this.

Basically, in the case of ridge regression it's deriving `lambda.max` (i.e., the value of `lambda` that causes all coefficients to vanish) from `alpha = 0.001`, which would be exactly 1000 times larger than `lambda.max` derived from `alpha = 1` (the LASSO case).

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "fix it", since the range of meaningful `lambda` values changes depending on your value of `alpha`.